# deny mach-loop server

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I my application I have two target. I need to communicate between the two target. So I register one app as server which has been given an identifier and server name.
I have tried to retrieve the proxy by using the following code. The identifier name has been set to second target. When I call the server object from the second target as under, i got deny mach-loop in the console.

```
    id proxy = nil;
    proxy = [[NSConnection rootProxyForConnectionWithRegisteredName:@"MYSERVER"
                                                               host:nil] retain];
```

The above proxy object I could get when I disabled the sandboxing. But, when i enabled the sandboxing  i could not get the proxy object. What could be the reason behind this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Distributed Objects connection being prevented by the sandbox.

It sounds like you need to read about how the sandbox works.

XPC might be a good alternative to Distributed Objects, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: :Even we can make the communication using NSConnection between the secure application group by setting bundle identifier of one another in the entitlement. here is the link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW5

Answer (score 0):

We can do so by using the entitlement property. We have to set the bundle identifier of one another app here is the link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW5